# SQL database design: comma separated lists as columns or a better solution?

Tags: mysql, sql

I saw that here everyone says comma separated lists is a bad practice for db design. Here I want to store 200K email headers in a database. Is there any better design for "to: ", "cc: " and "bcc: " other than comma separated lists? Each of these three headers may have random numbers (from 0 to many) of email addresses... Also, I may need to compare a "From: " in a row with another "To:/Cc:/Bcc:" in another row later. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes - comma separated is a very bad idea.

Have a table for your email addresses. The columns should be:

```
header_id
address
type (to/cc/bcc)
```

Then have another table for the actual message header (assuming there is other stuff to store as well). That will have an id (the primary key) which will be referred to by the header_id.